# Can I remove the var keyword

Tags: javascript, events, window, coordinates

The following code is taken from the 'JavaScript by Example Second Edition'.

I think the code

```
if (!e) var e = window.event; // Internet Explorer
```

should be

```
if (!e) e = window.event; // Internet Explorer
```

What do you think? Is it right? Or maybe the code should remains as is?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mouse Coordinates</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getCoords(e) {
            var x = 0; // x and y positions
            var y = 0;
            if (!e) var e = window.event; // Internet Explorer
            if (e.pageX || e.pageY) { // Firefox
                x = e.pageX;
                y = e.pageY;
            }
            else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
                x = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft
              + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
                y = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop
                + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            }
            // x and y contain the mouse position
            // relative to the document
            alert(x + ", " + y);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div style="background-color: aqua; position: absolute; top: 50px"
                onmouseover="return getCoords(event);">
                <h1>Mouse positions are relative to the document, not the
&lt;div&gt; container</h1>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Attaching event handlers using HTML attributes is *not* best-practice

Comment: @danwellman: It depends on the context.

Comment: @TimDown Please provide an example of an acceptable context

Comment: @danwellman: 1. When creating a page that loads slowly and it's vital that script-enhanced elements are interactive as soon as possible. 2. Knocking up a small trivial web page as quickly as possible. 3. Creating a web page that has to work on extremely old browsers.

Comment: @TimDown 1. Don't make pages that load slowly. 2. So, the number of standards we should follow is inversely-proportionate to the size of the site? 3. IE6 is the oldest browser in general use, and it supports proper event binding...But all this is irrelevant - the fact that there are *occasional* times when best-practice and industry-standards need to be ignored, doesn't mean that they aren't best-practices. The OP is questioning *3 characters* in an example script, yet using an event-binding technique that is emphatically *not* recommended.

Comment: @danwellman: Fair enough. I disagree with you but this is not the place to thrash it out.

Comment: @danwellman: ... although I do want to make one point: event handler attributes were a standard (still are) long before `addEventListener()`.

Comment: @TimDown It's not me you're disagreeing with, I didn't make it a best-practice (proper event-binding). The style attribute was a 'standard' long before CSS, that doesn't mean using CSS over the style attribute isn't also a best-practice.

Comment: @danwellman: I was picking up on your use of "standards" where you probably meant "best practices".

Comment: @TimDown I did mean best-practice, which is why I said 'best-practice' in my first comment, which you disagreed with

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17177/discussion-between-tim-down-and-danwellman)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can remove the var statement inside that function.

Variables in functions are declared in scope in 2 ways, either via the 'var' keyword, or by being defined as a parameter being passed into the function.

Comment: The code function getCoords(e){...} has defined a parameter e, so I think the var e in the code  if (!e) e = window.event; // Internet Explorer  is still local variable, right?

Comment: If a function passes in a variable, that variable is declared within the scope of that function. Its basically the same as using 'var' on a variable within the scope of a function.

Answer (score 4):

The code is right as it stands, but would work without the `var` keyword too.

Since `e` is a formal parameter to the function (whether passed or not) there's no need to declare it `var`.

On MSIE `e` is not passed, so it gets assigned the value of the global `window.event` object instead.

Note that the `var` keyword on its own does *not* overwrite any existing value, it serves merely to *declare* the variable in the local scope.  If the variable already has a value then "hoisting" moves the declaration up to the top of the scope, but leaves any assignment where it was.

A more idiomatic way of writing this is:

```
 function getCoords(e) {
     e = e || window.event;
     ...
 }
```

Comment: It works well in IE 9.0 even if I delete the code if (!e)  var e = window.event; // Internet Explorer , why?

Comment: @user828896 I guess in IE9.0 MS finally conformed to the W3C DOM3 event model, and pass the event as a parameter to the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'd drop the `var`, because it redefines the local variable that is already established in the same scope (by virtue of being a parameter to the function).

The result should be the same, with `var` just being redundant, but it creates confusion.

Also note that `var` works a bit funny in Javascript, as it does not matter if it appears on top of the function or anywhere else, it will always affect the whole scope, even code *before* it:

```
x = 12;    // using the variable "before" it is declared works
var x = x + 1;
```

I would avoid it in conditional blocks (because it is so confusing).

Answer (score 0):

That `var` is doing precisely nothing and can be removed without affecting anything in any browser. The existence of a function parameter with the same name means that there is already a variable of that name defined in the local function scope (even if its value is `undefined`), in which case `var` is specified as a no-op.

All that being the case, I'd suggest removing it, as its presence can only cause confusion.

Answer (score -1):

When you omit the var keyword, the variable is created in global scope. So when you omit the var keyword in this case, you create a global variable e which can be read and changed by any other javascript function. Considering that "e" is a very common identifier, this could lead to some very unexpected bugs.

In general, you should always use the var keyword.

Comment: No. 'e' is being passed into the function, therefore defining it and setting its scope.

Comment: Are you sure? `e` is already defined as a function parameter.

Comment: @Salketer no, strictly it means if `e` is _falsey_.